# Characteristic classes over the real projective spaces ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}})$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Inspired by other users --- [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2847051/79069) and [others](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247026/79069), [also here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2846718/79069): We may explore the characteristic classes of real projective spaces ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}})$, in some sense, it is related to some sort of "sphere" when we consider the most simple case ${\mathbb{P}}_1({\mathbb{R}}) \simeq S^1$. We however like to know general $d$.

It is still worthwhile to know the basic characteristic class data of them:

1. Stiefel–Whitney class $w_i$: ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}})$ may be non-orientable and non-spin.
   Note 
   $$
   w_1({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}})) =d+1 \mod 2\neq 0, \quad \text{ if $d=0 \mod 2$}
   $$
   $$
   w_2({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=\frac{(d+1)d}{2} \mod 2,  \text{ if $d \geq  2$}
   $$
   Thus
   $w_2({\mathbb{P}}_1({\mathbb{R}}))=0$, and for $d \geq 2$, we have $w_2({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=0$ for $d=3$ or $0$ mod $4$.

More generally, we have for other $w_i$:
$$
w({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))={(1+a)}^{d+1},
$$
where $H^*({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}),\mathbb{Z}_2)=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[a]}{a^{d+1}}$

2. Euler class:
   $$
   e({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=?
   $$
3. Wu class $u_i$: is related to the Stiefel–Whitney class $w_i$ through Stenrod square, so
   $$
   u_i({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=?
   $$
4. Pontryagin class $p_i$:
   $$
   p_i({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=? \in H^{4i}({\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}), \mathbb{Z})
   $$
   We can consider all the $d=0 \pmod 4$ dimensions.
   e.g. $p_1(T{\mathbb{P}}_4({\mathbb{R}}))=0$ (yes?) and the frame bundle $p_1(F{\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}}))=?$.
5. Are there other helpful / useful Characteristic classes for real projective spaces ${\mathbb{P}}_d({\mathbb{R}})$ that are nontrivial (or trivial)? A list of such info is greatly appreciated.

Edit. Chern class $c_i$ removed.

Comment: $T\Bbb{RP}^d$ is not a complex vector bundle. It does not make sense to take its Chern classes.

Comment: when $d$ is even, is it possible (as said above)?

Comment: You can take the Chern classes of a complex vector bundle. $d$ even does not make that into a complex vector bundle; it's not even oriented, so it can't be made into one. (Complex vector bundles come equipped with a canonical orientation.)

Comment: That is fine - thanks - you can still give a negative answer (No) for that case - I am just asking - it is a legal question. Just a negative answer

Comment: @Mike Miller, Chern class removed. (Why) Did you vote down?

Comment: There is a bunch of information scattered in the literature and ME, so it is not a totally bad idea to gather them in a post.

Comment: I think $e(RP^4)$ is odd.

Comment: I think we have $$c_i (CP^d)={ d+1 \choose i},$$ $$p_i(CP^d) ={ d+1 \choose {2i}},$$ $$e(CP^d) =d+1,$$ $$u_1=w_1=0, u_2=w_2+w_1^2=w_2=d+1,$$

Comment: $$w_i(RP^d) ={d+1\choose i} \mod 2$$
$$p_i(RP^d) ={d+1\choose {2i}}^2 \mod 2,$$ 
$$e(RP^d) =d+1 \mod 2,$$ 
$$u_1=w_1=d+1 \mod 2, u_2=w_2+w_1^2={d+1\choose 2}+(d+1)^2 \mod 2$$